# What tools would you use to source a probiotic or other nutritional supplement that is accurately labelled?

Tags: supplement

Suppose someone wants a probiotic that contains *Oxalobacter formigenes*.  They see a paper ([Ellis, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4348557/)) that says two supplements sold with this label contain no culturable *O. formigenes* and no amplifiable *oxc* DNA.  Can you suggest means by which they could identify an *verifiable* source of this supplement, or any other product sold as a nutritional supplement in the U.S.?

(This question does not address whether nutritional supplements are effective if taken as *intended*)

Comment: I think the answer is there aren't any, but I look forward to being proved wrong.

Answer (score 1):

USP is a third-party verification certification: https://www.usp.org/verification-services/verified-mark

It's private rather than governmental. On the consumer side, it is intended to achieve the following:

> Seeing the USP Verified Mark on a dietary supplement label indicates
> that the product:
>
> - Contains the ingredients listed on the label, in the declared potency     and amounts. Tests have shown that contents of some
>   supplements don't    match the label and some contain significantly
>   less or more than the    claimed amount of key ingredients. USP
>   Dietary Supplement    Verification helps assure customers that they
>   are getting the value    they expect from a product they are
>   purchasing.
> - Does not contain harmful levels of specified contaminants. Some supplements have been shown to contain harmful levels of certain
>   heavy metals (e.g., lead and mercury), microbes, pesticides, or other
>   contaminants. At specific levels these contaminants can pose serious
>   risks to one's health.
> - Will break down and release into the body within a specified amount of time. If a supplement does not break down properly to allow    its
>   ingredients to be available for absorption in the body, the
>   consumer will not get the full benefit of its contents. USP Dietary
>   Supplement Verification tests products against performance standards.
> - Has been made according to FDA current Good Manufacturing Practices using sanitary and well-controlled procedures. Assurance of    safe,
>   sanitary, well-controlled, and well-documented manufacturing    and
>   monitoring processes indicates that a supplement manufacturer is
>   quality-conscious, and that the supplement will be manufactured with
>   consistent quality from batch to batch.

In part, getting the certification on a per-product basis involves:

> To obtain the USP Verification Mark, manufacturers must undergo:
>
> - Manufacturing facility audit for compliance with USP General Chapter <2750>:  Manufacturing Practices for Dietary Supplements and
>   FDA  current Good Manufacturing Practices (21 CFR Part 111)
> - Review of manufacturing and quality control product documentation;
> - Laboratory testing of samples of dietary supplements for conformance to standards of quality found in the USP–NF, or to
>   appropriate pharmacopeial or manufacturer specifications and
> - Off-the-shelf testing of USP Verified dietary supplements to confirm that the product continues to meet science-based quality
>   standards.